# Xen and KVM kernel compile slowdown

Tags: performance, virtualization, xen, kvm

In [this slide deck on Xen vs KVM](http://www.xen.org/files/xensummitboston08/Deshane-XenSummit08-Slides.pdf), the benchmarks indicate that CPU and disk is nearly as fast under virtualization (~10% slowdown). Yet virtualization slows down a kernel compile by more than a factor of 2. What causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Linux kernel compile is a process heavy operation (lots of short-lived processes).  Process creation/destruction involves setting up and tearing down MMU state.  MMU virtualization is expensive (especially in software).  There is a [VMware whitepaper](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/Perf_ESX_Intel-EPT-eval.pdf) that shows the improvement in compile-time benchmarks when hardware MMU virtualization is used.  I don't think the hardware used in the referenced slide provides hardware MMU virtualization.  I don't know if either KVM or Xen support it (but I suspect so).

Comment: see also this interview with Keir: http://vimeo.com/5422005 He describes the differences between hardware acceleration with page tables and software shadow page tables and how workload is important in terms of performance.